# Container with persistent filesystem

Tags: linux, debian, docker

how to get docker container almost as a VM ? I mean I need to have debian or ubuntu with persistent filesystem (every file  needs to stay after reboot / reload (especially /home/ /etc/* /var/* )

I cannot use VM due to CPU limitations

Comment: Maybe [toolbx](https://containertoolbx.org/) could be interesting? _Tool for containerized command line environments on Linux_

Comment: Does it have to be docker, or are you open to other containerization technologies (such as `singularity`)? Because if you want to use container as a VM, docker (whose main use case is to containerize applications) might not be your best fit, while other solutions might be more appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Any container runtime I've encountered either has a way to "commit" a container state into a "snapshot", or to simply not discard any changes made.

`podman help commit` / `docker help commit` are your friends.

But I honestly think both `docker` and `podman` already do exactly what you want: Unless you explicitly call `podman run` with `--rm`, the container remains where it was once it exits. Find the container you want to continue using `podman ps`, and start it with `podman start`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a distribution using systemd, I would suggest you use systemd-nspawn, which uses host kernel (like docker) for the containers and has filesystem persistency like VirtualBox VMs.

Some useful getting started information can be found here for Arch Linux and Debian:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-nspawn

https://wiki.debian.org/nspawn